# SQL Server Setup failure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i uninstall sql server 2008 r2 and then install it but now i receive an error:

### TITLE: SQL Server Setup failure.

SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:

MsiGetProductInfo failed to retrieve ProductVersion for package with Product Code = '{A2122A9C-A699-4365-ADF8-68FEAC125D61}'. Error code: 1605..

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

Answer (score 3):

1. go to start menu
2. Run -> regedit
3. Edit `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\UpgradeCodes`
4. rename `UpgradeCodes` to `UpgradeCodesOld`
5. Reinstall SQL SERVER again

Comment: Hi @moez.  Thanks for your first post on ServerFault, but I'd like to remind you that it's primarily an english language site.  I've translated your answer from French with the help of Google Translate, but I'd like it more if you'd do this yourself in future!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**[Reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2009/06/13/upgrade-from-sql-2005-to-sql-2008-might-fail-with-msigetproductinfo-error.aspx)**

> SOLUTION (Worked at my end)
>   ********************************* Get the Product Code = '{0826F9E4-787E-481D-83E0-BC6A57B056D5}' from the error message that
>   you are getting.
>
> Byte reverse the first part from 0826F9E4 to 4E9F6280. Search in the
>   registry under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\UpgradeCodes and try to
>   find a match.
>
> Take a backup of the registry and delete the parent key. Re-run the
>   Upgrade and if it fails again for a different GUID, then repeat the
>   steps stated above.
>
> In my case, I had to repeat these steps thrice as there were 3 other
>   locations where I needed to change the product code. Then the setup
>   was successful.

Comment: this solution for upgrade from sqlserver 2005 to sqlserver 2008 but i uninstall sqlserver 2008 and install again it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are TOTALLY desperate, you can try the following PowerShell script that saved me a few times.
That PowerShell script generates a ".bat" file, that you can run for completely uninstalling SQLServer. Please do a THOROUGH review of what's in that .bat file before executing it! Possibly, execute things one step at a time:

```
# Be careful with that axe, Eugene.
#
# Generate a bat file named 'uninstallSQL.bat' to completely uninstall SQL Server from a machine.
# Content of the .bat file MUST be reviewed before execution, in order to REMOVE things you want
# to keep.

Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall | 
select @{Name='Guid';Expression={$_.PSChildName}}, @{Name='Disp';Expression={($_.GetValue("DisplayName"))}} | 
where-object {$_.Disp -ilike "*SQL*"} | 
where-object {$_.Guid -like '{*'} | 
% {"rem " + $_.Disp; 'msiexec.exe /x "' + $_.Guid + '" /passive'; ''} > uninstallSQL.bat
```